# What is purpose of php74-syspaths and is php74-syspaths not only used in conjunction with SCL?

Tags: php, mysql, centos

I am building a RPM using Jenkins (in an existing project - I am just having a peek into the source code, did not create this myself). During the "Resolving dependencies" it is identified that php74-syspaths must be installed.

```
---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.4.45-17.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.45-17.el7.remi for package: php-mysqlnd-5.4.45-17.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.45-17.el7.remi will be installed
---> Package php74-syspaths.x86_64 0:1.0-1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php74-runtime(x86-64) = 1.0-1.el7.remi for package: php74-syspaths-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php74-php-common(x86-64) for package: php74-syspaths-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php74-php-cli(x86-64) for package: php74-syspaths-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
---> Package pkgconfig.x86_64 1:0.27.1-4.el7 will be installed
```

1) It is unclear to me why it installs php74-syspaths. It is not listed in my rpmlist.txt or specified in my .spec file. Also the logging does not say explicitly that there is a dependency on php74-syspaths.

2) What actually is the purpose of php74-syspaths. As far as my understanding goes *-syspaths is used when using "software collections". But as far as I am aware we are not using `scl`.

3) Why php74? The latest stable PHP is 7.3. See https://www.php.net/downloads.php.

4) This `php74-syspaths` makes that `php74-php-common` is installed. And this conflicts later with `php-common-7.3.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64` which is wanted by `php-mysqlnd`. Some more details:

`php74-syspaths` depends on: `php74-php-common`

```
1285 ---> Package php74-syspaths.x86_64 0:1.0-1.el7.remi will be installed
1286 --> Processing Dependency: php74-runtime(x86-64) = 1.0-1.el7.remi for package: php74-syspaths-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
1287 --> Processing Dependency: php74-php-common(x86-64) for package: php74-syspaths-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
1288 --> Processing Dependency: php74-php-cli(x86-64) for package: php74-syspaths-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
```

`php-pdo` depends on `php-common.x86_64 0:7.3.10-1.el7.remi`:

```
1466 ---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:7.3.10-1.el7.remi will be installed
1467 --> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.3.10-1.el7.remi for package: php-pdo-7.3.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
1468 ---> Package php74-php-cli.x86_64 0:7.4.0~rc3-24.el7.remi will be installed
1469 ---> Package php74-php-common.x86_64 0:7.4.0~rc3-24.el7.remi will be installed
1470 --> Processing Dependency: php74-php-json(x86-64) = 7.4.0~rc3-24.el7.remi for package: php74-php-common-7.4.0~rc3-24.el7.remi.x86_64
```

therefore it installs: `php-common.x86_64 0:7.3.10-1.el7.remi` whereas `php74-php-common.x86_64 0:7.4.0~rc3-24.el7.remi` was already installed earlier. This causes the conflict?

```
1550 ---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:7.3.10-1.el7.remi will be installed
1551 --> Processing Dependency: php-json(x86-64) = 7.3.10-1.el7.remi for package: php-common-7.3.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
```

The conflict is shown at the end:

```
1608 --> Running transaction check
1609 ---> Package dejavu-fonts-common.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
1610 --> Processing Conflict: php74-syspaths-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64 conflicts php-common
1611 --> Finished Dependency Resolution
1612 Error: php74-syspaths conflicts with php-common-7.3.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64
```

To resolve these issues/questions I guess I have to do quite a bit of research.

Comment: please explain how php74-php-common conflicts with php-common ? and open an issue to track this on https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues

Comment: I added some details in 4). Does this answer your comment? I can open/duplicate the issue on github if you like.

Comment: I still don't see any conflict

Comment: Added one more section to 4) which shows the actual conflict detection at the end of the log file (sorry - missed that).

Comment: Ok, this conflict is there by design, as all these syspaths packages provide /usr/bin/php, only one can be installed

Answer (score 0):

the **syspaths** package exists to be able to install a SCL and use it as the default system version. It exists for various collections, including official ones.

The only case I can see where this package is pull, is that some package requires `/usr/bin/php` which is part of this file. Such package should requires `php-cli` instead.

I will try to see if this can be improved, but don't really see how.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the hint :). There is a RPM which requires ```/usr/bin/php```. I will try to sort out why and see if this "requires" can be replaced by ```php-cli```.